# Can I dinamically add new fields to my models/serializer/db ?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I´m developing an application using Django Rest Framework, and I have a problem. I´m trying to make the application as flexible as possible, so i wanted the possibility to dynamically add new fields to my models.
For example:
I have the model robot with fields id and version.
But then the user wants to add a new field, the owner of the robot.
What can i do so that with that I can can make the model and serializer reflect that new field. I can see how can i easilly add a new field to the database, but then the model and the serializer will not reflect this change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i wanted the possibility to dynamically add new fields to my models.

Short answer: you can't.

Long answer: you can use a related model where each record will represent a "field" for a given `Robot` instance, ie:

```
class RobotField(models.Model):
     robot = models.ForeignKey(Robot)
     fieldname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
     value = models.TextField()

     class Meta:
         unique_together = [("robot", "fieldname")]
```

But then properly handling the value (and it's type), validations, etc etc, and most queries involving those "fields" will become a PITA.

Or you could store "user-defined" fields as json in a kitchen-sink TextField, but then let's not even talk of SQL queries...

The point is that most often than not, adding a field to your schema means adding quite some business domain code using the field too - because usually the point of adding a field is to support some business rule.

FWIW peoples have tried to come with "zero-code user extensible models" apps for years and I yet have to see any app that actually succeeded in doing so. The results have always ended up in bloated code bases filled with antipatterns (like storing user-written code and templates in the db) and exhibiting abysmal runtime performances - AND with a UI so complex that users pay developpers each time they need any of the evolutions they were supposed to be able to do by themselves, paying big bucks for this since the bloated code base and convuluted models means that something as simple as adding a simple fields in a models now takes five times more work.

IOW : keep it simple stupid - code is quite often the simplest configuration tool.

Comment: It's not often that I agree with bruno but this pretty much sums is it up very well. +1 One disagreement though is using TextField for JSON. Both postgresql and mysql now have native support for JSONFields.

Comment: @e4c5 I'm aware pgsql had a decent support for json but not about something similar in mysql. Gonna get a look at it.

Comment: Django doesn't yet support the mysql json field but hopefully it will be there soon

Comment: This being said: this doesn't solve the problem of associated business rules, validations etc ;)

Comment: most definitely not. I am in full agreement.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using postgreSQL, you could make use of the [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField) and save the additional variables into this one field as key-value pairs.

Comment: I taught of that, but that imposes a problem. 
It will not reflect for all the Robots. If i add a new field i would had to iterate over all the robots to add the new field